# Track drag & drop actions with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm used to track clicks on elements on my web app using Google Tag Manager (a trigger to detect a click on an element with a specific ID, and a tag to send an event to GA4 when that trigger is detected).

Now I have an element that can be *dragged and dropped*. What's the easiest way to **track drag and drop** actions on elements?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several drag event you can use. [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event).
I think you can take a look first to decide which event is you expected. And doing the event listener to the dom. Then push the datalayer for GA4 configuration